# Tweepy StreamListener: Tweet when a specified account Tweets

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, bots, tweepy

I have a Twitter bot that is following one specific account.
When that account Tweets, I want my bot to Tweet.

So far I have the below code:

```
import tweepy
import time
import sys
import inspect

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
auth.secure = True

print "Test Message"

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
            if status.user.screen_name.encode('UTF-8').lower() == 'xxxxxx': #account I am following
                api.update_status('Test Tweet')  # tweet that is sent from my bot 


myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=MyStreamListener())
myStream.filter(track=['xxxxxx'])
```

However, when I run this code from the command line, it runs without a problem but does not react to any Tweets from the specified account.

Comment: you know that Python 2.7 is end of life as of today?

Comment: Hey @AndyPiper, yes I'm aware - I've been working on a project that uses 2.7 so have done the same for this one.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the `if` statement within your `on_status` method isn't properly indented.

If that's not the case, to properly debug this, you need to add an `on_error` method to your `MyStreamListener` class so that you're able to determine what, if any, error/status code is being returned by Twitter's API.

See [the Handling Errors section of the Streaming With Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#handling-errors).

Comment: Hey Harmon, thanks for the reply. I'm pretty certain it's not an indentation issue as this would be flagged in my terminal output. I have put an on_error method as youj suggested....now when I run the script, I it is not doing anything - as in when the specified twitter account tweets, nothing happens.

Comment: No Harmon, no error response code...I've put in a print 'test message', when I run the script this prints and then it the script just hangs and doesnot nothing when specified account tweets.

Comment: Are you printing that within the error handler? Because if so, then you're receiving an error response.

Comment: Nope the print message is before  the class and method, I've updated op with new code.

Comment: Again, your `on_error` method isn't properly indented. If you're receiving a 420 error response status code, that means you're being rate limited. See [the Twitter API's documentation for HTTP response status codes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes).

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, I am using sublime text and running script on a macbook, normally if I have indentation issues, this is flagged by terminal...not the case here, no error messages being receieved. Also, as I post above, I'm not receiving 420 error message, the script is just freezing.

Comment: [Indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) Since the lines after your `if` statement in your `on_error` method are not indented, this will raise an `IndentationError`. I'm not sure why you're attempting to specifically check for the 420 status code then.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Harmon, my newbieness is shining through here. Yes, I am understand indentation and am definitely not receiving and indentationerror messages, so that is not the issue. I followed your handling error link suggested earlier, but have got myself confused...will remove now, but that still does not solve issue.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you need to use an error handler to determine what status code you're receiving.